# Regular expression for unusual characters?

Tags: regex

What would the regular expression be to detect unusual characters, like the ones found here:
http://www.theworldofstuff.com/characters

So for example, what would the expression be to only allow letters, numbers and the symbols found on a keyboard (.$%^, etc.)?

Comment: What kind of keyboard? There are lots of different keyboards. In particular, I believe non-US ones have a number of symbols outside the ones you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought it'd be useful if I posted exactly how I did this in the end, so here you go:

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z !\"£$%^&*\\(\\)_\\-\\+\\={}\\[\\]:;@'~#<,>.\\?/`|§]
```

Not sure if it was just a Java thing, but I had a hell of a time working out which characters needed escaping. :p

Comment: That doesn't match `éèçà«»äßë‘ðüïŀöö© ↓¬¿×÷¡æâ€êþÿûîœô` but I have all these on my keyboard ;-( and most of them are letters.

Comment: Your keyboard is crazy.

Comment: @DamienBlack: May be, but I use it every days and most of these letters.

Comment: @M42 I only need to take into account english-based keyboards, e.g. America and UK. So only the symbols I allowed are needed. :p

Answer (score 0):

You just have to list everything you want. Something like:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*\(\)\\\?\{\[\]\}:;<>~`"'/+-\., =_]
```

Be careful to escape any characters that might be confused as part of the regex with `\`

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the ASCII charset with the following regular expression:

```
/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/
```

In order to only match the [printable part of ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters):

```
/^[\x20-\x7E]*$/
```